# Chrome Extension: chrome crashes when chrome.tabs.create is called from background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension that retrieves the last closed tab. However, when I run it on MAC, the chrome will hide itself(crashes), though the last url is indeed opened in a new tab when I reopen chrome from the Dock.

Wish to get your help, thanks!

When the browse loads, the following error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined on background.js line 10
```

`   Here is the background.js:

```
var tabToUrl = {};
var count = 0;
var urlRemoved = {};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  tabToUrl[tabId] = tab.url;

});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo) {
  urlRemoved[count] = tabToUrl[tabId];
  count++;
  delete tabToUrl[tabId];
});  

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(msg.method == "openLast"){
    while(count > 0){
      count--;
      chrome.tabs.create({'url': urlRemoved[count]}, function(tab){});
    }  
  }
  //alert("Removed Site Reloaded");
});`
```

Comment: Is the missing semi-colon at the end of "var urlRemoved = {}" and error or just a typo?

Comment: @Xanco thanks! that is a typo; I will update it in a second : )